# If email delivery fails for one single user, does it fail for all users in the group?

Tags: windows-7, email

So I sent one email to multiple email addresses (and also even more email addresses were in the “cc:” section). One of the email addresses was typed incorrectly and therefore failed to send.

Does this mean that the email failed to send to all recipients? In other words, if email delivery fails to one user, does it fail to all users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> …if email delivery fails to one user, does it fail to all users?

Nope. If it fails for one user, it fails for one user. When you “cc:” or “bcc:” a list you send it to the mail server which then will send the message to each person it’s told to send it to individually. So it’s not an “all or nothing” kind of deal.

If it were an “all or nothing” kind of deal, the aunts and uncles of this world would never be able to “cc:” or “bcc:” every person they know the forwarded emails they get each day!